# Python can't find installed modules

Tags: python, python-module

I've used these modules before, even in a Python script inside a folder where I have other working scripts. Here's my imports:

```
import os
import sys    
import urllib.request as urllib, simplejson as json, requests
import subprocess
import Popen, PIPE
import time
```

I get this in my console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "party.py", line 4, in <module>
    import urllib.request as urllib, simplejson as json, requests
ImportError: No module named request
```

How come? I've tried

```
sudo pip install request
```

..but with no luck. What is causing this?

Comment: I recommend using import this way: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

Comment: @Milo Tried, no luck tho. Same error.

Comment: That code will only work with python 3.x, not 2.x What version are you using?

Comment: @Keith Oh, 2.7. Coded on my PC and transfered to my linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what python version are you using? urllib.request seems to be python3

v2.7

```
>>> import urllib.request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named request
>>>
```

v3.3

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> urllib.request
<module 'urllib.request' from '/usr/lib/python3.3/urllib/request.py'>
>>>
```

Comment: I'm using 2.7, will upgrade. Cheers